# Remove elements which contain specified content

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple divs containing tables, one of it is like this:

```
<div id="apple">
    <table width="30%" height="2%" cellpadding="0" border="0px" align="left" >                  
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;</font></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Obviously it looks empty but occupies a paragraph in HTML. So I applied JavaScript to remove the table.

```
var ap = document.getElementById("apple")
if(ap.textContent==" " || ap.textContent=="&nbsp;"){
   ap.remove();
}
```

It seems that I failed to find the "empty" divs. How can I find correctly and remove the whole div?

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/uLjae/4/)

Comment: It's not failing to find the elements. It's failing to execute. Read the errors in the JS console and try fixing them.

Comment: shouldn't it be `ap.textContent`?

Comment: @DevZer0 You are right!

Comment: If you do `alert(ap.textContent.length);` you will see that there are many more white space characters than just one space. E.g. all the line breaks after tags or the spaces for the indentation. These are all text nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `.remove()` on a DOM element and I think you are using the non-defined variable `div` by mistake. Try:

```
var ap = document.getElementById("apple")
if(ap.textContent==" " || ap.textContent=="&nbsp;") { //change div for ap
   //go to the parent and remove the element
   ap.parentNode.removeChild(ap); 
}
```

Your fiddle should look something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C8YUE/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for my mistake. Do you mean by this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/uLjae/5/) ? But still not correct..

Comment: You are confusing things a bit, I'm affraid I can't explain exactly why your code is wrong in a comment, but try this working example with comments: http://jsfiddle.net/C8YUE/1/

Comment: That's very clear to me! Thank you and I know how to make it!

Answer (score 2):

The `textContent` will include all the text nodes, the whitespace in the table. Try the following :

```
var ap = document.getElementById("apple");
if (!ap.textContent.trim()) {
    ap.parentNode.removeChild (ap);
}
```

The `&nbsp;` is converted to a space in `textContent` so no need to test for it.

Forked fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/kQq5b/1/

Comment: remove it's not a method of a dom element

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right, I modified my code. However the fiddle works and `ap` has a `remove` method (at least in Chrome)! A mystery that needs some investigation.

Comment: I think is part of the DOM4 so I'm technically incorrect, it exists, just not everywhere

Comment: Ah thanks for checking, Chrome has it but neither Firefox nor Opera (can't test IE ;-) I updated the fiddle to conform to my answer.

Comment: My previous code simply used remove() and works good under Chrome. Thank you two masters, and I will code stricter in the future. @HBP&NicoSantangelo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to your problem, based on your fiddle:

```
<div id="apple">
    <table width="30%" height="2%" cellpadding="0" border="0px" align="left" >                  
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><font face="Arial">&nbsp;</font></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
var ap = document.getElementById("apple")
var content = ap.textContent;
content = content.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
content = content.replace(/\s/g,'');
console.log('Content: "' + content + '"');
if(!content.length){
   ap.parentNode.removeChild(ap);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/orlenko/pvWTP/